# Ramsey Number $R(4,4) = 18$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I wanted to know how to prove that $R(4,4)= 18$ without having to draw the graph.

I assume that I will have to start by proving that $R(4,4) \geq 17$. Can I also prove it by using $R(3,4) = 9$?

Answer (score 6):

The recurrence $R(r,s) \leq R(r-1,s)+R(r,s-1)$ implies that $R(4,4) \leq 2R(3,4)=18$. So it suffices to prove $R(4,4)>17$ by exhibiting a graph on $17$ vertices that does not contain a $K_4$ and whose complementary graph does not contain a $K_4$.

[This page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey44.shtml) exhibits such a graph (and the picture is not strictly necessary).

Comment: That graph is vastly more elegant than I thought it would be.